# Load array file to Big query

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking for effective way to upload the following array to Big query table
in this format :

**Big query columns (example)**

```
event_type: video_screen
event_label: click_on_screen
is_ready:false
time:202011231958
long:1
high:43
lenght:0
```

**

**Array object**

**

```
[["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011231958","1","43","0"],["buy","error","2","202011231807","1","6","0"],["sign_in","enter","user_details","202011231220","2","4","0"]]
```

I thought of several options but none of them seems to be The best practice.

Option A: Upload the following file to Google storage and then create table related to this bucket - not worked because of file format, Google Bigquery can't parse array from Google bucket.

Option B: Use by backend (node.js) to change the file structure to CSV and upload it directly to Bigquery - failed because of latency (the array is long, more than my example).

Option C: Use Google Appcript to get the array object and insert it to Bigquery - I didn't find a simple code for this, Google storage has no API connected to Appscript.

Someone deal with such a case and can share his solution? What is the best practice for this case? if you've code for this it will be great.

Comment: Option D, write the file in csv or another supported format directly. Then you can insert the rows into BQ easily

Comment: What's the size of the longest line in your file?

Comment: 100K lines per file, but I process multiple files every 5 minutes.

Comment: Lines per file is not problem. What's the longest line in your file? 1 single line how long is it?

Comment: 6 columns, max 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the file from GCS to BigQuery into a table with 1 single `string` column. So you get 100K rows and one single column.

Essentially you will have a table that has a JSON in a string.

Use [JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array) to process the JSON array into `elements`

then later extract each position into its coresponding variable/column and write it to a table

here is a demo:

```
with t as (
    select '[["video_screen","click_on_screen","false","202011231958","1","43","0"],["buy","error","2","202011231807","1","6","0"],["sign_in","enter","user_details","202011231220","2","4","0"]]' as s
),
elements as (
select e from t,unnest(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(t.s)) e
)
select 
    json_extract_scalar(e,'$[0]') as event_type ,
    json_extract_scalar(e,'$[1]') as event_label,
from elements
```

the output is:

[image]

Comment: It sounds good but, how to load the file from GCS to BigQuery into a table with 1 single string column and  100K rows? BigQuery can't parse this type of file [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

Comment: @idan Load as a CSV format, and specify a separator that doesn't not exists in your row, such as TAB or ~, or ^. This way you load the entire line as 1 column.

Comment: All the file is entered to one single cell, how to create a separate cell?

Comment: That means all your input is on one single line. It's not a problem if the file is entered in one cell. That is exactly what you need. Now use my example to explode it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right thing to do, all the data will enter to one single cell? there is no limit? String limit?

Comment: Limit is 100MB for a cell. The most you can do is, make sure you have a file that has multiple lines even with many arrays in rows.

Comment: Limits are here: 100MB is documented for a cell when using CSV import. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas